# AttributeError: Python 'filter' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, object, filter

I am having issues with

AttributeError: 'filter' object has no attribute 'sort'

Below is the whole error message:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Data/PROMISE2012/Vnet3d_data/promise12_Unet_segmentation-master/promise12_segmentation-master/codes/train.py", line 231, in <module>
    n_imgs=15*10**4, batch_size=32)
  File "D:/Data/PROMISE2012/Vnet3d_data/promise12_Unet_segmentation-master/promise12_segmentation-master/codes/train.py", line 166, in keras_fit_generator
    data_to_array(img_rows, img_cols)
  File "D:/Data/PROMISE2012/Vnet3d_data/promise12_Unet_segmentation-master/promise12_segmentation-master/codes/train.py", line 48, in data_to_array
    fileList.sort()
AttributeError: 'filter' object has no attribute 'sort'

Process finished with exit code 1

def data_to_array(img_rows, img_cols):
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=0.05, tileGridSize=(int(img_rows/8),int(img_cols/8)) )

    fileList =  os.listdir('TrainingData/')
    fileList = filter(lambda x: '.mhd' in x, fileList)
    fileList.sort()
```

Comment: `filter` returns a `filter` object. If you want a list then do `fileList = list(filter(lambda x: '.mhd' in x, fileList))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python 3 filter returns iterable. and you are calling sort method on iterable hence getting an error.
Either wrap iterable in list

```
fileList = list(filter(lambda x: '.mhd' in x, fileList))
```

or instead of `fileList.sort()` pass iterable in a sorted method

```
fileList= sorted(fileList)
```

[Python 3 doc for filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 3.  Filter returns an iterable `filter` object, but it has not `sort` method.  Wrap the filter object in `list`.

```
fileList = list(filter(lambda x: '.mhd' in x, fileList))
```